# Will reconfiguring Zabbix clear out the database?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, zabbix

I have a quick question. I need Zabbix to have access to CURL. However, I don't think that when it was installed the with-libcurl was set:

```
./configure --enable-server --enable-agent --with-mysql --enable-ipv6 --with-net-snmp --with-libcurl
```

Is it safe to run that command again even though we have Zabbix setup and monitoring all of our servers? We really need CURL support however we don't want to lose our current monitoring setup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so if anyone else has this question, no it does not. I took a backup of the DB just in-case.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it but I don't see why it would.

The server binary you built is just a user of the database. You had to loaded the SQL files during deployment to initialize it, not the server binary.

All it's going to do is access the database and process events and triggers.